# Trying to copy executable jar file into AWS ec2 instance but getting permission denied error

Tags: amazon-ec2, executable-jar

I want to deploy a spring-boot executable jar file into Amazon EC2 instance. I successfully logged in into the instance using pem file but I am unable to copy my Jar from local system location into ec2. the command I am using is

```
scp -i /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/recovery-key.pem /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/foodapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-15-222-1-81.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

I am getting an error of permission denied like below:

> Warning: Identity file /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/recovery-key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> lost connection

Screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: Try `chmod 600 /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/recovery-key.pem`

Comment: For permission issues error would have been "It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are logged into the ec2 host and trying to reference a file which is present in your local.

Run below command to transfer the file from local to ec2 hosts.

```
scp -i /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/recovery-key.pem /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/AWS/foodapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-15-222-1-81.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

Don't login into the EC2 host, just run the above command from your local.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works for me now. I was trying it from inside of the instance, my bad:)